# Node API to Create new Area Path?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am creating a Azure DevOps extension that utilizes the Rest API and the Node API client.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api

I am trying to create a process that creates a new team within a team project.  The Core api group has methods to work with Teams, and I can successfully Create a Team.  However, I see no way to create a new Area Path for this team.

I can't find an API that would seem to allow me to either create a new Area path for that Team, or even if I did, how I would set the Team's Area to be that new Area Path.. What am I missing? There HAS to be an API way to work with Area, but really don't see it in the API Documentation.  I've looked through the WorkItem APIs, the Project-related APIS, and I can't find any Area-related calls.

Here is some code on how I've created a Team. that works fine.

```
var coreApiObject: CoreApi.CoreApi = await vsts.getCoreApi();
var newTeam:CoreInterfaces.WebApiTeam =  {name: teamName,
description: 'Onboarding Backlog for ' + teamName,
id: undefined,
projectId: projectRef.id,
projectName: projectRef.name,
url: undefined};

var projectId:string = "";
if(projectRef.id)
{
    projectId = projectRef.id;
}
var teamResult:CoreInterfaces.WebApiTeam = await coreApiObject.createTeam(newTeam, projectId);
```

Comment: Ahh! Found example of creating an area under ClassificationNodes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/create%20or%20update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#create_an_area

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thanks for the response.. Well, I have been attempting to create an Area Path, but it's been failing (I created an issue on GitHub here that hasn't had a response https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/327) And I still see no way to set the team's backlog or iteration.  That is the biggest hurdle for me at this point.. being able to automate the creation of a team is pointless if the team isn't usable or needs manual intervention to make it useable.  I guess there HAS to be a way to do it, I just don't see where.. help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hmm, looks like the API under Work has an area for TeamFieldValues that will help with Area Path, and TeamSettings that will help with iteration path... I will explore those, still really need to get the API to let me create an Area Path for the team